# REJECTED - Bad HELO - Host impersonating somedomain.com

Tags: email, exim

For "somedomain.com" we send transactional mail from the main server and have a second server to handle bulk mail, lets call it "news.somedomain.com". The servers are interconected by a back-to-back connection so the network traffic between servers are not billed by the ISP. The back-to-back interfaces are 10.1.1.1 and 10.1.1.2. Is there some way in cPanel to whitelist 10.1.1.2 so 10.1.1.1 would not perform any checks for this host?

The bounces are handled by a catch-all account on the main server, but mail from news.somedomain.com is being rejected.

I tracked the problem to the following router:

```
drop
    condition = ${if match{$sender_helo_name}{$primary_hostname}}
    message   = "REJECTED - Bad HELO - Host impersonating [$sender_helo_name]"
```

How do I make changes to this router permanent (I hate cpanel but my boss loves it)?

I lost my changes every time cPanel updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES -

To do this you need to edit your Exim Config

You can find the Exim Configuration Editor in the Service Configuration section of WHM. To begin, navigate to the configuration editor

From here you may choose to add certain ip addresses (or ranges) to the various access lists:

- Whitelist: Backup Mail Hosts (bypass
  all SMTP ratelimits)
- Whitelist: Auto white list known
  mobile device providers
- Whitelist: Bypass SMTP time sender
  verifcation checks
- Whitelist: Bypass all SMTP time
  recipient/sender/spam/relay checks
- Whitelist: Trusted Mail Hosts/IP
  Blocks (bypass all SMTP time checks
  except recipient verification)

I personally think that cPanel is great for the end-user...(painful if your used to manually setting this yourself however.... I agree) If your loosing changes everytime cpanel updates - simply open a ticket with them.   Their support is exceptional.
Anyhow - save them here and they should not be overwritten.